# How to insert variable as a string into MySQL in Java

Tags: java, mysql, string

Suppose I have two variables and I know their values:

```
v1=11.1f
v2=22.2f
```

I can insert a string of `"11.1,22.2"` into a field in this way.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
pstmt.setString(1, "11.1,22.2");
```

but what should I do if I do not know their values. If I do it in the following way,

```
pstmt.setString(1, "v1,v2");
```

it is also a string, however, v1 and v2 are just characters but not variables any more.

So how to put variables instead of their values into a String and then I retrieve their values when I need them.

That reason why I asked this question is because I want to put an ArrayList in one row in MySQL. If so I thought I need to put float[] as a string in one field. Please tell me there will be another way to do it.

Comment: So you want learn about string concatenation?

Comment: If you mean something like "v1=11.1,v2=22.2" then there's no way but to do it manually. If those vars are class members you might use reflection to get the names and values, but I assume that's beyond your skill for now.

Comment: It's hard to see what you're asking here and therefore hard to sensibly answer your question.

Comment: he wants to change "11.1,22.2" string into "v1,v2" string

Comment: @Marek Sebera yes, that is what I want to do

Comment: @awoodland I just edited my question, please check whether it is clear or not.

Comment: @wzb5210 - the question is quite a bit clearer now (I still have to guess what `pstmt` is though, see http://sscce.org/ for a guide on asking really good questions). I'm upvoting now because -4 now seems too low.

Comment: @awoodland Thanks for your suggestion! I am learning to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can create strings with placeholders using:

```
String result = String.format("%s,%s", v1, v2);
```

If you are using JDBC, you can use a PreparedStatement, for example:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE table1 SET column1 = ? WHERE column2 = ?");
int i = 1;
statement.setInt(i++, v1);
statement.setInt(i++, v2);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

For creating JDBC queries the PreparedStatement is preferable because it guards you against typing and character escaping problems.

EDIT: Per request, an alternative way (don't know if it's better though):

```
MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat("{0},{1}");
Object[] args = new Object[] {v1, v2}; // achtung, auto-boxing
String result = form.format(args)
```

(this one is on the house, but untested)

Comment: +1, for sensibly mentioning `PreparedStatement`s given SQL background to question.

Comment: Thank you very much, `String result = String.format("%s,%s", v1, v2);` works for me.

Comment: I try to avoid String concatenation as much as possible; either String.format or StringBuilder for me.

Comment: @Adriaan Koster Do you have an better way?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
// float v1 = 11.1f;
// float v2 = 22.2f;
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.put("v1",new Float(11.1));
ht.put("v2",new Float(22.2));
String a = "11.1,22.2";
Enumeration e = hashtable.keys();
while( e. hasMoreElements() ){ 
    String key = e.nextElement();       
    a.replace("/"+e.get(key)+"/",key);
}
System.out.println(a); // prints out "v1,v2"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think I may mislead you. Before I putting 'v1' and 'v2' into a String, I did not know its value. I expect to put them in a string and then I can get their values back when I need them.